# Talend job running with slow transfer rate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, talend, amazon-rds

I am new to talend and have very limited experience in it ,
My task required to perform daily incremental update from sql rds to redshift on daliy basis,
however my job runs with very slow transfer rate
details are listed below

my sql rds query is

```
SELECT
    *  
FROM
    test.ankit2 
WHERE
    id > (SELECT COALESCE(max(id), 0) as id FROM test.stagetable)
```

ankit2 is the table in myrds 
and 
stagetable is table in redshift
and used tmap component to link the component from rds input to redshift output component
Please have a look at the image

Please have a look and provide your suggestion 
Any help will be appreciated
regards
Ankit[Talend Etl job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXpwT.png)

Answer (score 2):

For the best Redshift performance, use `tRedshiftOutputBulkExec` component instead of `tRedshiftOutput`. It will use selected S3 bucket for storing data as csv, and utilize superfast `COPY` command (with this approach I managed to hae 20000 rows/s write speed).

It will be better to do direct unload from RDS to S3 if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ..
But i dont have the s3 api keys along with me to perform the copy operation

Comment: If you have access to the EC2 instances, you can try to install Talend on the EC2 instance. Your bandwidth might be bottleneck in this process. 8 rows/s is really slow.