# Incremental update using talend

Tags: amazon-redshift, talend, amazon-rds

My requirement need to perform incremental update from myrds to redshift every day ,
I have a primary key in the rds table as 'id'
Is there any possible way I can save the id in a variable in talend and when the 
nxt time talend job runs it validate the sql

where sorucerds id > destredsfhit id

[testjob](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlaHn.png)

so it should only update the rows which were inserted after last update
I have tried but its not working as desired 
I am a newbie in talend so if any suggestion would be of great help to me

regards

Comment: You can query Redshift for `MAX(id)` and then select from RDS where id is greater than retrieved value.

Comment: yeah i did the exact same thing in the other query that i have posted in 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35404230/talend-job-running-with-slow-transfer-rate

But now i wish to save it a variable and then use the max(id) saved from that variable

Answer (score 0):

Use `tMySqlInput` componet (or whatever you use to query against RDS) and write following query:

```
"select MAX(id) as maxid from <your table name>"
```

Click on the `Guess Schema` button to generate schema for the output of the component. Put `tJavaRow` component next to it and drag main row to it. Create an empty variable in your Context (In Repository pane). Let's call it `maxid`. Go back to the `tJavaRow` componet and write following code:

```
context.maxid = row1.maxid
```

This will assign `maxid` value from the `tMySqlInput` output to the context variable. Which you can use in your job afterwards.

Comment: Really thanks for the help but still its not working,
Please have a look at the details

tmysqlrdsinput1 
"select  max(id) from test.test2"

then used tjavarow component as 
context.maxid = row1.maxid;

and then passed it into input string into 
tmysqlrdsinput2  as 

"Select  *  from test2  where id > ' " + context.maxid + " ' "

and then saving the output of the query as tmysqloutput as  
stagingtable


The job is running without any error but its not performing any update on staging table 
can u suggest what could be the issue

Comment: I'm sorry, the first query has to be against Redshift database. You have to select the maximum id of the already processed records, additionally put NVL(MAX(id), 0) to ensure if there is no records in Redshift your second query can select all IDs>0.

Comment: But i tught of creating a staging table in myrds and then appending the data from staging table to redshift ,
How even when ever my source table is increased then max(id) is also increased along with it 
Is there any variable or any component available in talend which will save my last max(id) and then i can write a query to select and the display only the rows which were inserted after last saved max(id)

Comment: You have to query against target table, to get last inserted record. Then select from the source where ID is greater than maximum in the target. You don't need staging table..